# how to get the Class generated by gen-class in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am using some java lib which require the access the class generated by `gen-class`

```
(ns cljfx.test
  (:import some.java.Lib))

(gen-class :name Main)

(defn -main [& arg]
  (Lib/method-require-class-arg (classOf Main)))
```

the prototype of `method-require-class-arg` is

```
public static void method-require-class-arg(Class someClass) {
  // ...
}
```

How to write the `(classOf Main)` part in the first snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gen-class` example is incorrect.  If you use

```
(gen-class :name cljfx.test.Main)
```

then just `cljfx.test.Main` will return the Class object.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I've updated my answer to show a correct gen-class usage.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Added the missing `:name` in the question. I am still curious about why `cljfx.test.Main` works but `Main` (in the root package) does not.

Comment: Clojure doesn't fully support classes in the root package (which java doesn't recommend, anyway). You could use Class/forName as @Ankur mentioned, but that's slower than using a fully qualified name directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class/forName` method.

Ex: `(Class/forName "java.lang.String")`

In your case it should be `(Class/forName "Main")` and you need to make sure you enable `aot` in your project.clj